# How to ignore first line of .txt when using Scanner class

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have a text file that reads:

```
Description|SKU|Retail Price|Discount
Tassimo T46 Home Brewing System|43-0439-6|17999|0.30
Moto Precise Fit Rear Wiper Blade|0210919|799|0.0
```

I've got it so that I read everything, and it works perfectly, save for the fact that it reads the first line, which is a sort of legend for the .txt file, which must be ignored.

```
public static List<Item> read(File file) throws ApplicationException {
    Scanner scanner = null;
    try {
        scanner = new Scanner(file);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        throw new ApplicationException(e);
    }

    List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();

    try {
        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            String row = scanner.nextLine();
            String[] elements = row.split("\\|");
            if (elements.length != 4) {
                throw new ApplicationException(String.format(
                        "Expected 4 elements but got %d", elements.length));
            }
            try {
                items.add(new Item(elements[0], elements[1], Integer
                        .valueOf(elements[2]), Float.valueOf(elements[3])));
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                throw new ApplicationException(e);
            }
        }
    } finally {
        if (scanner != null) {
            scanner.close();
        }
    }

    return items;
}
```

How do I ignore the first line using the Scanner class?

Comment: Just fire an empty `scanner.nextLine` before your while loop?

Comment: Just call the nextLine() function once before processing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simply calling scanner.nextLine() once before any processing should do the trick.

Answer (score 5):

how about calling scanner.nextLine() as outside your loop.

```
scanner.nextLine();//this would read the first line from the text file
 while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            String row = scanner.nextLine();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
scanner.nextLine();
while (scanner.hasNext()) {
      String row = scanner.nextLine();
      ....
```